# how to install jsonwebtoken package

Tags: node.js, express, npm, jwt

[image: 1]

I don't know why `jsonwebtoken` package is not installing. I installed other packages also like express and other but `jsonwebtoken` package didn't download. Please tell me the reason

Comment: Could you send a higher resolution picture, cannot read the text. And did you install other packages in the same folder that you are trying to install jwt?

Comment: its showing on top node-base 64 and when i go to npm and watch its dependecies its showing node-base64 and same is showing on my terminal

Comment: and i recently install other too they do install but jwt didnt because may be it has node-base64 issue

Comment: 1. I wonder if you really mean this [jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt) package (9 years old and not maintained) or rather want to install [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)? You even write 'jsonwebtoken' in the question but installed 'jwt' 2. the problem has nothing to do with Visual Studio Code, you don't install it "on VSCode", you just use the command line in the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your folders on the left are not showing any node_modules, so I don't think you have installed anything yet, or you might not be in the right path when running npm install. Verify the path, and make sure that you are in the right folder. Case sensitive mistake maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong with `jwt` library leading those errors. (I encountered the same)

Try `npm i jsonwebtoken` instead.